# WordPress blog on second level in URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new with WordPress and I need little help.

I'm preparing small portfolio with blog, so I decided for WordPress. There will be some pages `/about/`, `/contact/` etc., and then `/blog/`.

I set in wp-admin in permalink URL for blog to `/blog/%postname%/` and it's OK for articles. When I open article, URL is `/blog/my-new-article/` but list of all posts I need on url `/blog/` too.

I'm not able to do this, when I changed URL of wordpress, even pages are `/blog/about/`, but should be only `/about/`.

Is it possible to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Appearance > Themes > Customize and you'll have a sidebar tab called 'Static Front Page'.

This allows you to set your Homepage, and your Blog page separately. Tell Wordpress to display a static page for the Front Page, and then select which page you would like for your Homepage, and your Blog page.

So if you create a page, and set that as your Homepage, and then create a page called Blog, and set that as your Blog page (The Blog page can be empty, as it will dynamically generate the loop of article posts).

Then in your Permalinks Settings page keep the `/blog/%postname%` setting.

That should fix it.